# php variables in sql statements for login

Tags: php, mysql

I am fairly inexperienced with php and sql and I am having an issue with php variables in the insert into SQL statement.

I have a SQL Table :

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    userID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    username VARCHAR(256),
    password VARCHAR(256)
);
```

This isn't the way I made the table as it was made in phpmyadmin but that is exactly how it is

the PHP is so , there is validation code aswell but it is not necessary:

```
$userUsername = $_POST["username"];
$userPassword = $_POST["password"];

$sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO users(username,password) VALUES ('$userUsername','$userPassword');";

$insertquery = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlinsert)
               or die ("Problem with insert query");
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, you need to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

Either you need to assign auto increment to primary key (userID).
Or you have to pass value for it like

```
$sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO users(userID, username, password) VALUES (1, '$userUsername', '$userPassword');";
```

Comment: you can accept this answer or click on up arrow. so if someone searching for the same issue then they can also get guidance.

Answer (score 0):

if you have Auto Increment in ID then leave a blank first

```
$sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO users(userID,username,password) 
VALUES ('','$userUsername','$userPassword')";
```

Or fill it with ID if not Auto Increment.

```
$sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO users(userID,username,password) 
    VALUES ('1','$userUsername','$userPassword')";
```

And as already mentioned in comments of your post your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection.

can use [PDO Prepare Statement](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp),too not necessarily ofcourse

Comment: No need to change API entirely, `mysqli_*` (which OP is using) offers prepared statements too.